# Provide an algorithm O(n^3 log n) with simple operations?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Provide an algorithm computing performance O(n<sup>3</sup> log n). The algorithm should contain only simple operations.

Any idea of how to approach this problem?...I am studying for the computer science GRE. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to write an outer loop that runs O(n<sup>3</sup>) times and an inner loop that runs O(log n) times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n * n * n; i++) {
   for (int j = 1; j <= n; j *= 2) {
       // ... do nothing ... //
   }
}
```

Note that the inner loop runs log n times because the value of j after k iterations of the loop is 2<sup>k</sup>, and as soon as k ≥ lg n, we'll have j = 2<sup>k</sup> ≥ n.

Another option would be to write a recursive function whose runtime, via the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), works out to O(n<sup>3</sup> log n).  One way to do this is to have a function that makes 8 recursive calls to subproblems of size n / 2 and does Θ(n<sup>3</sup>) work per call:

```
void silly(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n * n * n; i++) {
            // ... waste time ... //
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            silly(n / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: As @Nuclearman pointed out, you can also get runtime O(n<sup>3</sup> log n) by sorting an array of size n<sup>3</sup> using an algorithm like quicksort or heapsort.  More generally, running any algorithm whose runtime is O(n log n) on an input whose size is n<sup>3</sup> produces a runtime of O(n<sup>3</sup> log n).  This uses the fact that log (n<sup>3</sup>) = 3 log n = O(log n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Another possibility is sorting a list of size O(N^3).

Comment: I could have, but it since you already have a fairly through answer, seems better to simply help make yours more complete.

Comment: Seems it was the right way to go, as I would have neglected the general case even though that was were I was coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You can backwards solve this using algebra.

A recursive T(n^3/3) algorithmn gives you your O(n^3), so now you just need a T(n/2) for the log.

N must equal K for this to work

procedure T(n,k) is

T(n^3/3,k) if n >=0

T(n,k/2) if k>=0 and n<=0

It will run the O(n^3), then the O(log n), therefore no matter what, the minimum runtime for this program is O(n^3 log n)

How did I get the values for the T function? Let's start by solving T(n/2).

T(n)=T(n/2)+1. The plus 1 is how long the basic operations take once we finish recursion.
T(n/2) = T(n/4) + 1 thus T(n) = T(n/4) + 2

We can extrapolate to say that T(n) = T(n/2^k) + k.

T(1) is our base case, so let's n/2^k equal to 1 and solve for k.

K = log n (base 2)

So that means that this function has big O of O(log n).

The same math can be done for T(n^3/3).

Let me know if this doesn't make any sense.